# Python: IndexError: list assignment index out of range - date conversion?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date

I'm new to Python as of three days ago so please understand!

My attempted code is below. I'm trying to import DAX price data from Yahoo and work with it but I can't get past the error below which I think is something to do with the conversion of the date?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Temp\Pandas_read_import_to_Numpy.py", line 25, in <module>
    date, highp, lowp, openp, closep, volume, adj_closep = np.loadtxt(stock_data,
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1134, in loadtxt
    converters[i] = functools.partial(tobytes_first, conv=conv)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from pandas_datareader import data

def bytespdatestr2num(b):
    return mdates.datestr2num(b.decode('utf-8'))

# Set the start and end date
start_date = '2019-11-01' 
end_date = '2019-11-27'

# Set the ticker
ticker = '^GDAXI'
# Get the data
stock_data = []
stock_data = data.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start_date, end_date)
stock_data.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(stock_data.tail(20))
for col in stock_data.columns: 
    print(col) 

date, highp, lowp, openp, closep, volume, adj_closep = np.loadtxt(stock_data,
                                                    delimiter=',',
                                                    unpack=True,
                                                    skiprows=0,
                                                    converters={1: bytespdatestr2num})

x = 0
y = len(date)
stock_data_v2 = []
while x < y:
    appendLine = date[x],highp[x],lowp[x],openp[x],closep[x],volume[x]
    stock_data_v2.append(appendLine)
    x+=1

print(stock_data_v2)
```

Comment: What does `stock_data` look like?  I'm not sure, but I suspect it isn't getting as many columns as you expect (7)?

Comment: Date          High           Low          Open         Close    Volume     Adj Close
224 2019-11-28  13259.290039  13215.709961  13247.610352  13245.580078  36771000  13245.580078

Comment: That's one line of the data so it has 7 columns but also has the index number at the beginning, could that be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: wrong delimiter!